# What does ./ mean in Unix/Linux

Tags: bash, unix

This might look wrong, but I know that using ./ you are basically "BASH"ing your scripts in Linux/Unix environment. For Windows users, this is same as running an .exe file from command prompt. However, I don't understand why use ./

Is it because ./ means "RUN" in short or does "./" have a specific meaning in UNIX like environment?

P.S. I know that cygwin allows you to execute batch files using ./ prefix.

Answer (score 3):

`./file` is functionally equivalent to `file` in all circumstances except one.

The exception is that a command or script without a directory causes the shell to search all the directories in the `PATH` variable, which generally does not include the current directory.

So to run an executable from the current directory, you need to specify a path, and `./` is the simplest way to do this.

In Windows the equivalent `.\` is unnecessary because the current directory is implicitly searched.

Answer (score 0):

`.` indicates the current directory - the folder you're in, and `/` is a directory separator, separates a parent directory name from it's children files or another subdirectories, for instance: `/bin/bash` - here `/` is the root directory, `bin/` is it's subdirectory, and `bash` is a file (as you see there are no separator in file names, as they can not have children nodes)

it's all the same on windows (dos), expect the separator character is **backward slash** (`\`)